# Parse JSON array file with JSONPATH

Tags: arrays, json, jsonpath

I want to parse this with JSONPath:

```
[
  [50.4154134372953,-1.28486558931069,"CLASS B",9,205,0,"UK",431500382,3,4],
  [50.3058858494047,-0.976070494820637,"CLASS B",9,239,0,"UK",2750350,21,2]
]
```

Can you help with that please?

Comment: _What_ do you want to parse it into? Language?

Comment: I want to know the JSONPATH e.g. $.* to get any item of the array.

Comment: So you want to use JSONPath, whose implementations for several languages are available at http://code.google.com/p/json-path/ and http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If the object is:

```
[
  [50.4154134372953,-1.28486558931069,"CLASS B",9,205,0,"UK",431500382,3,4],
  [50.3058858494047,-0.976070494820637,"CLASS B",9,239,0,"UK",2750350,21,2]
]
```

Then `"$[0]"` will return:

```
[50.4154134372953,-1.28486558931069,"CLASS B",9,205,0,"UK",431500382,3,4]
```

And `"$[1]"` will return:

```
[50.3058858494047,-0.976070494820637,"CLASS B",9,239,0,"UK",2750350,21,2]
```

You can do it two levels deep as well. `"$[0][4]"` will return:

```
205
```

You can also extract the elements of the array into a list with `"$[*]"`, which will return a list of 2 elements. The first being:

```
[50.4154134372953,-1.28486558931069,"CLASS B",9,205,0,"UK",431500382,3,4]
```

and the second being:

```
[50.3058858494047,-0.976070494820637,"CLASS B",9,239,0,"UK",2750350,21,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using DefiantJS, you can search a JSON structure with XPath syntax. This library extends the global object JSON with a search function.

In this scenario, you can write something like this;

```
var data = [
  [50.4154134372953,-1.28486558931069,"CLASS B",9,205,0,"UK",431500382,3,4],
  [50.3058858494047,-0.976070494820637,"CLASS B",9,239,0,"UK",2750350,21,2]
],
search = JSON.search( data, '//*/*/*' );
```

Check out this fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/5NfeM/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
JsonPath.with(jsonResponse).param("name", "getName").get("findAll { a -> a.name == name  }")
```